# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message Laravel 5.8 and Ajax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to store multiple emails in a prospect system. I'm building the system with Laravel 5.8. I'm trying to put the emails using the AJAX request. And not return in a page using redirect, but keep in the same modal.

This is for a system that in the past, can only store one email. But a user says that need to store more than one email to the client. Now i'm trying to create a functionality that in a prospect, you can add multiple emails and when the user will send a proposal, will show all emails stored in that prospect.

I'm need to use the AJAX request to do it. Now I try to use the method "POST" to proceed with my functionality, i put it in my route, my view and my AJAX request.

This is my route

`Route::POST('prospect/emails/save','ProspectEmailsController@store')->name('prospectEmails.store');`

This is my view

```
 <form id="emailModalProspect" method="POST">
          @csrf
          
          <input hidden name="prospect_id" id="prospect_id" type="text">

          <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="prospect-email-name">{{ __('Nome') }}</label>
              <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-email-83"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input class="form-control" id="prospect-email-name" name="name" placeholder="Put the email owner" type="text">

              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <label class="form-control-label" for="prospect-email-email">{{ __('Email') }}</label>
              <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-email-83"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input class="form-control" id="prospect-email-email" name="email" placeholder="Put the email" type="email">
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="text-center">
              <button type="submit" id="save-email" class="btn btn-primary my-4 store-email">Store</button>
          </div>
    </form>
```

This is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request){ 
    $prospect_emails = ProspectEmails::where(['prospect_id'=>$request->prospect_id])->get();
     
    ProspectEmails::create(array_merge($request->all(), ['company_id' => Auth::User()->company_id], ['prospect_id'=>$request->prospect_id], ['tag'=>false]));

    $p_email = ProspectEmails::where('prospect_id',$request->prospect_id)->get()->count();
    
    $update_at = Carbon\Carbon::now();

    Prospect::where('id', $request->prospect_id)->update(['updated_at' => $update_at, 'prospect_emails'=> $p_email]);
   
    return response()->json();
}
```

And this is my Ajax request

```
$('.open-email-modal').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        let p = JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-entity')); //the id of the prospect that i want to insert the emails
        
        let modal = $('#emailModal');
        let form = $('#emailModalProspect');

        $('#prospect-email-name').val(p.name);
        $('#prospect_id').val(p.id).change();

        form.submit(function(e){
          if(p.id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{route('prospectEmails.store')}}",
                type: "POST",
                data : form.serialize() ,
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                  if(data){ 
                    console.log(data); // here, in console, show a empty array like it "[]".
                  }
                }
              });
            }
        });
        modal.modal({show : true});    
  });
```

Now always I'm trying to register a new email, show this message:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>
> No message

In console show this error.

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/prospect 405 (Method Not Allowed)

The strange that store the data in my database, but show it. What happens to show this message?

> I change to PUT method. At first it works, but show the token and the things that i store in URL. It's not what i want.

Comment: can you share your request?

Comment: Open your dev console to see any errors in the console

Comment: I will edit the results in my question. but in the console.log(data) show a empty array "[]" and show the result:  prospect:1 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/prospect 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: What are the headers you're sending, are you sending the csrf token?

Comment: at first yet, i imagine.

Comment: Above of my code in ajax, i added this code to: $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }});

Comment: Might be worth while to do a php artisan route:list and get an idea of what routes Laravel things as set. Also did you happen to cache routes?

Comment: the route is showed like a POST normally when i put this command in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is defined as `prospect/emails/save`, but you're POSTing to `prospect`, which apparently doesn't exist as a POST route.

Post to the correct route and it should work fine. Adding an `action` to your `<form>` should do the trick:

```
<form action="{{ route('prospectEmails.store') }}" ...>
```

Comment: Awesome, it works perfetly. Now i need a new problem that i don't know how can i proceed in this new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732469/how-can-i-insert-2-actions-using-html-javascript-and-laravel

Answer (score -1):

please use

```
Route::any('prospect/emails/save','ProspectEmailsController@store')->name('prospectEmails.store');
```

or

```
Route::post('prospect/emails/save','ProspectEmailsController@store')->name('prospectEmails.store');
```

instead of

```
Route::POST('prospect/emails/save','ProspectEmailsController@store')->name('prospectEmails.store')
```

please use routes like this

```
Route::get($uri, $callback);
Route::post($uri, $callback);
Route::put($uri, $callback);
Route::patch($uri, $callback);
Route::delete($uri, $callback);
Route::options($uri, $callback);
```

Comment: what options and patch routes do? can you explain to me?

Comment: what's the difference between put and post?

Comment: can you explain in answer?